# Latin Modern Roman Unslanted licensing

Tags: latin-modern, licensing

I downloaded a family of Latin Modern font from latex website some time ago. It's licensed under [LPPL license](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt), but I still don't understand if that means that I can use it on a public website, somewhat dedicated to profit.

Anyone?

Comment: We here can't giv legal advise... just state our opinions as rank amateurs

Comment: In general, legal questions are off-topic not only for TeX-sx but across the whole StackExchange network as they depend on the local legal framework and require specialist knowledge about the law rather than (say) TeX.

Comment: Also note that the LM fonts are released under the GUST Font License: see http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern.

Comment: @JosephWright correct, but GFL and LPPL are legally equivalent; the only difference between GFL and LPPL is that GFL asks in case of changes to "please" rename the font files. But this is a request not a binding restrictions of the license (though hopefully everybody doing modifications will obey this wish).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Almost certainly true, but if you are going to ask for legal/license advice I think you have to be very careful to pick exactly the license involved.

Comment: @@FrankMittelbach Ok, so does conversion for webfont, where some characters get thrown out, counts as modification?

Comment: I've closed here as 'off topic' as legal questions are very tricky for us to give a solid answer on. The current answer gives a 'intention' point of view, which is of course very useful but isn't quite the same as a legal one. (This is not a criticism of the question or answer, it's more of a policy thing that we have to be realistic on our limits in this area.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can. The LPPL does not restrict the use of the WORK (which is what you are asking about) the license only defines under which conditions the WORK can be distributed and modified.

It states:

> Activities other than distribution and/or modification of the Work are
>   not covered by this license; they are outside its scope. In
>   particular, the act of running the Work is not restricted and no
>   requirements are made concerning any offers of support for the Work.

The word "running" may sound a little strange in the context of fonts, but that is due to the license initially being designed for software programs.

In short, you can use any WORK under this license for whatever you wish including commercial usage.

Note: I'm one of the principal authors of the license, so you can see the above statement as a notice of intent.

Comment: Frank, good man, may God of your personal choice bless you endlessly :)